# MySQL store values for a limited time in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a theater tickets booking website (user-> book and pay / admin->manage sells from a webinterface).
I use a table in mysql database to handle tickets: each column is a specific day and each line of this day is a boolean to know which seat is booked (1 for booked, 0 for free).
But i wanted to improve this system and have a third state for when the user is currently booking online and has not paid (finalized the order) yet to prevent the other users to book his seats.
So, is there a way to save this third state (-1 for example) for a limited time only (about 15min) in the tickets table ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onInsert/onUpdate` trigger with `SLEEP(<seconds>)`.

Updated:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON tickets
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> DO SLEEP(60000);
    -> UPDATE tickets SET status=1 WHERE id = NEW.id;
    -> END;
    -> //
```

Pay attention that triggers can be set from root only.

Comment: Thanks for the update
actually, I may do something wrong because it still doesn't work...
`mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON tickets_table
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> DO SLEEP(600);
    -> UPDATE tickets_table SET column = '1' WHERE column = '0' LIMIT 5;
    -> END;
    -> //`

Comment: I think it cannot work in my case because the columns of each variable tables (one tickets table per year) are variable too (col = unique representation day and row = state of each seat(id of the table))

Comment: I think that the solution could be making a sort of asynchronous php request to update the tickets table when the delay is reached... What do you think about that ?

Comment: It works well with a `curl_post_async` function found on SOF, but now, I don't know how to cancel the request (if the custumer paid with success for example).